# colorbox is not working when I use the tree menu script

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

when I use the tree menu js then colorbox is not working. how can I resolve this.

I'm using the following tree menu js.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.markettrendsignal.com/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".videodisplay").colorbox({
            iframe: true,
            width: "670",
            height: "465"
        });
</script>
<script src="http://mtsbeta.com/js/simpletreemenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //ddtreemenu.createTree(treeid, enablepersist,opt_persist_in_days (default is 1))
    ddtreemenu.createTree("treemenu1", true)
    ddtreemenu.createTree("treemenu2", true)
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<td id="webinar_register">
    <a href="modules/video_display.php?Wvideo=<?php echo $wdate1[$k]['video'];?>"
    class="videodisplay">View</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi there,  posting that "it doesn't work" with code samples isn't really very helpful.  What appears in your js console?  Describe in detail what you're seeing, or better yet, post a link to your project. Just sayin'

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning colorbox after you've run createTree.